# Python PyQt5: Can I also insert a QPushButton into a database via SQL?

Tags: python, database, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

As the title suggests I want to know if it's possible to insert a QPushButton into a database via SQL?

```
    connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        db = 'myDatabase',
        cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)  
    cur = connection.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES("%s"), [QPushButton("Click me!")])
```

Comment: theoretically some objects can be converted to string (serialization/pickle) (and saved in database) and later reconstructed from string (deserialization/unpickle)

Comment: Why the heck would you want to do that? A button has no state that is worth saving.

Comment: I asked because I got the idea to insert in one cell a button to show a window with an image by clicking on it. Maybe a Link would be better than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `QTableWidget` to display the database, you need to add the button to the cell in the table:

```
    button = QPushButton('Show Image', self)
    button.clicked.connect(self.handleImageButton)
    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, button)
    ...

def handleImageButton(self):
    button = self.sender()
    item = self.tableWidget.itemAt(button.pos())
    if item is not None:
        print(item.row(), item.column())
        # get image data, etc ...
```